# How to split the name for student mark list

Tags: r

```
name=c("John Porter","Anne Theresa","Terry pATRIC","Fred nORTON ","Maria lOPEZ") 
exam1=c(92, 75, 10, 62, 79) 
exam2=c(93,77,49,66,85)

results=data.frame(name, exam1,exam2)     
results$avg=((results$exam1+results$exam2)/2)    
results$grade=cut(results$avg, breaks = c(0,49,69,79,84,100),labels =c("E","D", "C", "B", "A"))     
results

new=strsplit(as.character(results),"")
new    
lastname=sapply(new,"[",2)    
firstname=sapply(new,"[",1)    
results=cbind(firstname,lastname,results[,-1])    
results

results=results[order(lastname,firstname),]    
results
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the `new` variable, convert `results$name` to character, not `results`. Also, use `" "` (a blank space) to split the words, not `""` (no space). If you fix that one line, the code seems to work.

Change this:

```
new=strsplit(as.character(results),"")
```

to this:

```
new=strsplit(as.character(results$name)," ")
```